# Converting to Mongo/mongoose from Mysql with relations

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In a new project I started with MySQL but I want to convert it to mongodb / moongoose.

My pain here is the different relations I have in MySQL.

F.x. I have have users table

```
uid | firstname | lastname | email
```

and i housetable

```
hid | address | zipcode | city | ownerid
```

where ownerid is a user in the users table

I am a little unsure how I should design me schemas in mongoose to have an option a bit like the MySQL one.

My current user schema is like this

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    email: String,
    phone: Number,
    password: String,
    address: String,
    zipcode: Number,
    city: String,
    bankname: String,
    bankregno: Number,
    bankaccno: Number,
    userconfirmed: Boolean,
    confirmtoken: String,
    resettoken: String,
    resettokenexpires: Date,
    acceptmarketing: Boolean,
    lastloggedin: Date,
    disabled: Boolean
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field for an array of houses in your userSchema to break it up and allow a one to many relation. You can do this by using [subdocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html).

This could look something like this.

```
const houseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    address: String,
    zipcode: Number,
    city: String,
})

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    email: String,
    phone: Number,
    password: String,
    bankname: String,
    bankregno: Number,
    bankaccno: Number,
    userconfirmed: Boolean,
    confirmtoken: String,
    resettoken: String,
    resettokenexpires: Date,
    acceptmarketing: Boolean,
    lastloggedin: Date,
    disabled: Boolean,
    houses: [houseSchema],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mongoose [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), like this

```
const User = new mongoose.Schema({
    House: { type: mongoose.Types.Schema.ObjectId, ref: "House" }
});

const House = new mongoose.Schema({
    Number,
    Road: String
});

(async () => {
    const users = await User.find({}).populate("House");

    // users = [
    //     {
    //         _id: 373890hfjklfhjkfh,
    //         House: {
    //             _id: dhkdhdlhjkld,
    //             Number: 378930,
    //             Road: fhjdlhdjkld
    //         }
    //     }
    // ]
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to relate both the schemas, this might help you. If you want more info, https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/populate.html

```
const User = mongoose.model('User', new mongoose.Schema({
  firstname: {
  type: String,
 },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
 },
  email: {
    type: String
 }
}));

const Address = mongoose.model('Address', new mongoose.Schema({
  owner: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
   }
   //rest of your address schema
}))
```